# C# return results from nested if statements

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, int, nested-loops

I am attempting to have the for statement iterate and increase the number `i` from `0 to 100`.

This will be displayed on the screen.

My issue is not quite understanding what I want to return in the method (not Main) but if I need to return anything.

I don't want to return a int. I don't think I have a string to return as I want it to perform a function not return a value. I think I am messing up method types.

I want the method to simply go through the if statements and if a parameter matches then display the result on screen, if not move on to bottom and start again from for statement.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Project5
    {
      class Program
      {
        int i = 0;


        static void Main(int i)
        {
            do
            {
                for (i = 0; i < 101; i++)
                {
                    Words(); 
                }
            } while (i < 101);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string Words (int i) //<---Here I think I am using the incorrect method type
        {//Which then screws up the method when it is called above. I have been going                
        //through method types but dont see anything that when called just perform a         
        //function and displays results.

            string f = "Word1";
            string b = "Word2";

            if (i == 3)
            {
                Console.Write(f);

                if (i == 5)
                {
                    Console.Write(b);

                    if (0 == (i % 3))
                    {
                        Console.Write(f);

                        if (0 == i % 5)
                        {
                            Console.Write(b);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(i);  
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think u dont have to return anything. Just use void, not any int or string. And keep executing till 100..

Comment: There is so many odd things with this code.. You're not passing any parameter into words, and if you were, it wouldn't update the loop outside of it unless you passed it. Then, your ifs are all nested. I don't see how this would do anything other than print Word1 once.

Comment: I think I am trying to make the string method do to much work and need to break it up.

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone, I will be sure to mark as helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
static string
```

to

```
static void
```

then it doesn't have to return anything

Also you should probably remove the do loop as it is redundant, the for loop should be doing what you want (I think).

Comment: There won't be an infinite loop. Both loop cases say wait for i > 100 and they will both pass through because of the `i++` in the `for` statement.

Comment: oh good point, was thinking the for loop was declaring a new instance of i, but it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the return type not being `void` you have a couple of problems so far as i can see

1. You need to pass your variable `i` to the words method like this `Words(i);` in the for loop.
2. Remove the `while` around the `for` as they are accomplishing the same thing.
3. Your logic in Words is wrong. `i` cannot both be equal to 3 and 5 so nothing but your first `Console.WriteLine();` will ever execute. Instead you should unnest them so all of them get checked on every iteration.

Comment: No the first match wont break it. Its writing to the console and after that testing the second `if (i == 5)
`. Which it is not as we just determined that `i == 3`. My suggestion for you would be to search around a bit for some basic books regarding control flow, and probably programming in general :)

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, change the method signature from `static string Words` to `static void Words` and you know longer have to return anything in the `Words` method. `void` is a keyword that refers to nothing in the context of a method signature.

Also, you do not seem to be passing in the required parameter for `Words` when you call it in `Main`. I'm assuming instead of `Words();` you meant for `Words(i);`

Lastly, you may wish to look up the difference between a *static* class member and an *instance* one. In short, *instance* members can access *static* members of the same class, but *static* members **cannot** access the *instance* members. I bring this up because you declared `i` in the class as an *instance* variable but also create local `i` variables in both *static* methods. What ends up happening in your case is the *instance* `i` never actually gets used. Instead, both *static* methods use their own local `i` variable.